# How to add a static method into ATL object?

Tags: visual-c++, com, static-methods, atl, dllexport

I am trying to write a simple COM/ATL DLL following the link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/505791/Writing-Simple-COM-ATL-DLL-for-VS, but it does not mention how to add a **static method** to ATL object.

Can I add a **static method** to ATL object?

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: Static method to ATL C++ class - just like with any other C++ class. Static method to COM class or COM interface - those don't have static methods.

Comment: Static C++ methods cannot be exposed through an interface so are not usable from client code.  An interface method in C++ needs to be emulated with the *virtual* keyword, the opposite of a static method.  You can add a static method to an ATL class, just use the text editor.  Do note that you can use the [appobject] attribute in IDL, some runtime environments (like VB6 and VBA) support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the class wizard on ATL classes you get only the option to add methods to the COM interface. You have to modify the class manually when you want to add something that is not in the COM interface.

So you have just to add the static method with the text editor in the header file and of course you have to add the implementation in the  .cpp file.